# Windows/Linux System cloning and Re-imaging

Tags: windows, linux

Back in the day, I used Norton Ghost to image machines, servers, etc. save the images on a central server, and then used a bootable Ghost USB stick to rebuild machines from the saved images as needed. Complete system rebuilds in 15 minutes.

Bought 100 new desktops? Line them up, boot the first 5 from 5 USB sticks, by the time you want to get to the 6th, you pull the USB stick from the first, and progress down the line.

End user clicked a dodgy link? Don't know if it was malicious? We didn't waste time investigating anything. We just told the employee to go grab a coffee and by the time they came back, the whole machine was fresh (and with a roaming Windows profile, even user settings and preferences were maintained).

I just assumed that such capability was still available. Ghost went end of life in 2013, and while there are "cloners", they appear to be blunt instruments and aren't scriptable (to be able to pull things like roaming profiles, etc.) and don't use bootable media to rebuild as necessary.

Is there a successor to Norton Ghost? A way to image a machine, then boot off of media to pull down and re-apply the image with some scripting capability to reconnect resources? For use in an Enterprise setting? Bonus points for being able to image arbitrary OSes.

I know that M365 has tools for auto-provisioning once the device joins the domain, but I need something closer to the metal than that.

My Google-fu is finding what appears to be personal projects or fancy hard drive cloners.

Comment: Also wondering if there's anything around that can handle drive encryption tbh - for Win* bitlocker seems to be pretty common now.

Comment: Should be able to give the system imaging software a bitlocker key

Comment: Start at https://alternativeto.net/software/norton-ghost/ but the big problem will be the scripting

Answer (score 3):

@Archivarius is right (not wrong ;), dd is great but needs some linux fu.  For something out of the box and brain dead I'd go for [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/).  Disk to disk, disk to (network) image and the reverse, etc.  Super capable, super easy to use.

Answer (score 2):

Why not to use **dd** tool (or **rsync**, etc...)?

For example, make compressed image:

**sudo dd if=/dev/sdX bs=64k status=progress | gzip -c > imageName.img.gz**

restore:

**gunzip -c imageName.img.gz | sudo dd of=/dev/sdX bs=64k status=progress**